# JS V8 engine ignored characters

Tags: javascript, v8

I wanted to ask, are there any characters that are completely ignored by JS engine, specifically, V8? And I know comments exist but that's not what I'm looking for.

Comment: @dustytrash I mean, are there any characters that if you had `var something = fu[replace this with the character]nc();` it would work

Comment: No, why would there be any?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

V8 developer here. No, there are no such characters.

There is a sort-of related but different feature: within string literals, you can escape the line break, like so:

```
var s1 = "Hello\
World";
var s2 = "HelloWorld"
console.log(s1 === s2);  // true
```

This does not work outside string literals (like your `... = fu[...]nc();` example) though, so it's a special feature of string literal parsing, not a "character that's completely ignored by the engine".

Comment: Thanks for your reply, great to know that js engine developers look at questions related to their engine